# Increasing arrow head size in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I am using ArcMap 10.4. I have an arrow as my symbol for a line feature.  I am wondering how to increase the size of the arrow's head without increasing the width of the line portion itself.

How can I do this?

Nothing I try worked.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify at least one of things that you tried, and describe the outcome that was not acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

See video below, you need to drill down to the line decoration symbol.

*Click on image to enlarge.*
[image: Altering the arrow decorator of a line symbol]